# What is neo4j closest feature to sql stored functions?

Tags: neo4j, stored-functions

I'm new to neo4j and graph databases in general.

Given a complex Cypher query, that I don't want to store inside the application (or several applications), but keep centralized, what options are left to me?

In a SQL database I would use a stored function. Are UDF function the way to go in neo4j?
From the docs it seems to me that they're more a way to extend the database functionality by being able to access the graph internals, but I've just started studying them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the custom functions and procedures available in the apoc library.

https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/cypher-based-procedures-functions/

```
CALL apoc.custom.asProcedure('answer','RETURN 42 as answer')
```

```
CALL custom.answer() YIELD row RETURN row.answer
```